# Getting mimetype from URL in PHP on Windows

Tags: php, windows, mime-types

I try to write a script that would fetch some external resource and count it's size. To do so I need to detect if the given URL provides some binary file (i.e. graphics) or some HTML document. I thought of checking mimetype but when I run following code:

```
$finfo = new \finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
return $finfo->file($this->url);
```

I get the information `Warning: finfo::file(): Failed identify data 0:no magic files loaded in`. I've already uncommented the line `extension=php_fileinfo.dll` in my php.ini but for some reason there's no mimetypes definition. I run the code on standard xampp instalation.

How can I fix it? Or maybe you have some other ideas for such detection?

Comment: Do you get any errors from PHP?

Comment: Just the warning I quoted that the magic files are not loaded.